# Android application stops unexpectedly

Tags: android

In the emulator, it shows me the infomation: The application my_app_name (process pack_name) has stoped unexpectedly.Pls try again
What is the problem?

Because i just add many field in the layout.xml file?

I am a newbie in Android development. Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in LogCat.  You probably have a stack trace in there.  If you can't understand the stack trace post it here by editing your original question.

Comment: You can access LogCat via `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I just add a new xml file to define the listview field.and change the main xml 
This is the xml file: